# The usage of reverse() in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used two different ways to create a reverse list.
The first way:

```
>>> a=list(range(3))  
>>> a.reverse()  
>>> print(a) 
[2,1,0]
```

The second way:

```
>>> a=list(range(3)).reverse()
>>> print(a)
None
```

Why does the second way does not work?Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It fails because `reverse` changes the list in place (i.e. it does not create a new list) and like most functions that operate in place it returns `None`.

In your first example

```
a=list(range(3))  
a.reverse()
print a
```

It works fine as you capture `a` as the return value from `list(range(3))`, which returns a `list`. You then reverse that list in place and print it. All fine!

In your second example

```
a=list(range(3)).reverse()
print(a)
```

`a` is equal to the return value of `reverse()` (not `list(range(3))`).
`reverse` is called on a temporary list and returns `None`, which is the value assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the second way does not work?

`.reverse()` doesn't return a list (it returns `None`). It modifies the argument you pass into it.

You need to do it the same as the first method:

```
a=list(range(3))
a.reverse()
print(a)
```

Comment: Do you mean reversed()?reverse() seem to not exist.

Comment: it's supposed to be `a.reverse()` - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.reverse()` mutates the list, but does not return the list.

Why they chose to implement it this way, I don't know.  Perhaps to save memory.

Comment: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html - explanation by Guido why `sort`, `reverse` methods of `list` do not return `self`

Comment: That answers the question of why it doesn't return the value -- Guido has an esthetic objection to fluent coding -- but it doesn't answer why it is in an afunctional style to begin with.  Why does `.reverse()` return the reverse array and leave the original one unchanged?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more on your last question?